# darkened image issue css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an image and have it darkened and then image to expand when the mouse is hovered over it this so far is the Css and html I have:

```css
.module {
width:400px;
height:300px;
position:static;
overflow:none;
display:table-cell;
}

.module:hover {
-ms-transition:all 3s ease;
transition:all 3s ease;
-ms-transform:scale(1.05);
transform:scale(1.05);
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 3s ease;
}

.module .overlay{
  height: 100%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)
    );
}


.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 95%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

```html
<div class="module" unselectable="on">
                  <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news" target="_blank" unselectable="on"><img src="https://uelac.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/ITServices/PublishingImages/_DSC6407_jpg.jpg?csf=1&amp;e=QO7pRx" alt="test" unselectable="on"> </a>
                    <div class="overlay" unselectable="on">
    <div class="text" unselectable="on">Digital Training Services</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have all the parts working other than having the image permanently darkened, as can be seen when running the snippet in full screen(a little warning it can flicker a lot) it may be one of the position variables but I have tried all of them and it just doesn't seem to get it to how I would like it. Thanks.

Comment: should the image already be darken? or does hovering darken the image?

Comment: I would like it to be darkened from when it is hovered over

Comment: will it stay darken after the hover or change back to being the lighter color?

Comment: The darken should disappear afterwards it is hovered over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class name "transeffect" you might have to adjust the opacity to your needs. 
Remove overlay because you don't really need a overlay just to darken the image.

```css
.module {
width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
position:relative;
overflow:none;
display:table-cell;
}

.module:hover {
-ms-transition:all 3s ease;
transition:all 3s ease;
-ms-transform:scale(1.05);
transform:scale(1.05);
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 3s ease;
}




.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 95%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

img.transeffect:hover {
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity:0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="module" unselectable="on">
                  <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news" target="_blank" unselectable="on"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="test" unselectable="on" class="transeffect"> </a>
                    <div class="" unselectable="on">
    <div class="text" unselectable="on">Digital Training Services</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/4mj66wqs/

Comment: Thanks! what is transeffect? does it only effect the image and not the text?

Comment: transeffect is just a classname. you can make a classname of whatever name you want then declare what you want it to do. it only effect the img, unless you want to make it effect the text